# How does one set the default payment type for X-Cart

Tags: php, x-cart

I can't figure out how to set the default payment selected when going to the checkout page. Is there a way to set it up through the database, admin page, or a config file?

I'm using version 4.5.2 if that is of any help.

I also tried setting the order number to 0 to see if it would set my type of payment selected first, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you :

Find this file : include/checkout.php 
find this line below: give the payment id what you want to enable

```
// $smarty->assign('paymentid',        $paymentid);
$paymentid=14; // default payment selection
$smarty->assign('paymentid',        $paymentid);
```